Scroll-snap doesn't work when I scroll with two fingers on my touchpad
I'm trying to implement a scroll-snap effect on my website so that each section snaps into view as the user scrolls. It works perfectly when I use a mouse scroll wheel (works 1 time to 5...), but it doesn't work consistently when I use two-finger scrolling on a touchpad. Instead of snapping to the next section, the page scrolls smoothly and bypasses the snap effect.


body {
    font-family: Inter, system-ui, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  
    color-scheme: light dark;
    background-image: radial-gradient(at center, #0d1d31 0%, #0c0d13 100%);
  
    font-synthesis: none;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.scroll-container {
    height: 100vh; /* Full viewport height for the container */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Enables vertical scrolling */
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; /* Each section snaps to the viewport */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Hides scrollbar on Internet Explorer and Edge */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Enables momentum scrolling on iOS */
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Hides scrollbar on Firefox */
}

.step {
    height: 100vh; /* Full viewport height for each section */
    scroll-snap-align: start; /* Each section snaps to the start */
}

/* Hide scroll bar specifically for the container */
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; /* Hides scrollbar on WebKit browsers */
}
  <div class="scroll-container">
            <section class="step">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="menu-container">
                        <button>Contact</button>
                        <button>Resume</button>
                        <button>About</button>
                        <button>Certificate</button>
                        <button>Project</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <img src="./public/ICON.png" alt="icon" class="img-icon" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <div class="animated-background"></div>
                <div class="animated-background-solid"></div>
                <div class="size-slot-container">
                    <div class="slot-container">
                        <div class="intro">
                            <p class="greeting">Hey </p>
                            <h1 class="name">I'm MisTrale </h1>
                            <h2 class="role">FullStack Developer <span style="color: red;">Engineer</span></h2>
                            <p class="description">
                                I want to be a <span style="color: red;"> Full-Stack </span> Developer specializing in <span style="color: blue;">front-end</span>, <span style="color: blue;">back-end</span>, and <span style="color: blue;"> mobile </span> development using Flutter. 
                                I am passionate about creating seamless and efficient applications that provide real value. 
                                Actively seeking opportunities to leverage my skills in meaningful projects and contribute to the growth of the tech industry.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </section>
            <section class="step">
                <div class="aboutme">
                    <p>ABOUT ME</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="step">
                <div class="aboutme">
                    <p>NotMe</p>
                </div>
            </section>





It doesn’t work consistently when I use two-finger scrolling on a
touchpad.

I tested your code and found that the snapping works when scrolling gently on the touchpad, but if you give it a big flick, it will scroll right through the snap points all the way to the bottom.
CSS does provide a solution to this: the scroll-snap-stop property.

The scroll-snap-stop CSS property defines whether or not the scroll
container is allowed to “pass over” possible snap positions. The
effect of this property can be noticed on devices with a touchpad. Try
to scroll through all items with a single swing. Value normal should
pass through all pages, while always will stop at the second page.

.step {
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

Try this snippet. Use the full page link after running it, because scroll snapping works more consistently on larger viewports. Push the button to toggle scroll-snap-stop between normal and always, and observe the difference it makes when scrolling with the touchpad.


const sc = document.querySelector('.scroll-container')
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  sc.classList.toggle('stop-always')
  if (sc.classList.contains('stop-always'))
    evt.target.innerHTML = 'scroll-snap-stop: always'
  else
    evt.target.innerHTML = 'scroll-snap-stop: normal'
})
body, button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.scroll-container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.step {
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  padding: 1px 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stop-always .step {
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.step1 {
  background: cyan;
}

.step2 {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.step3 {
  background: lime;
}

.step4 {
  background: pink;
}

.step5 {
  background: yellow;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="scroll-container stop-always">

  <section class="step step1">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section class="step step2">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <p>
    Sed sed cursus leo. Nam molestie eleifend leo, nec fermentum risus maximus ac. Pellentesque eget placerat ipsum. Vestibulum tempor quam justo. Fusce dapibus turpis non ante faucibus suscipit. Fusce rhoncus eleifend ipsum et lacinia. Curabitur nec congue arcu. Mauris dignissim magna ligula. Nullam ultrices, metus sit amet ultrices porttitor, turpis ligula interdum enim, eu pellentesque purus quam ut arcu. Nullam aliquet vitae tortor vel tincidunt. Fusce maximus lacus diam, sed elementum ligula condimentum vel. Sed consequat orci ac nunc gravida, at accumsan magna porttitor.
    </p>
    <p>
    Mauris vulputate quam ac purus laoreet, nec ultrices eros placerat. Fusce id nisi ex. Nunc ornare tellus nisl, suscipit fermentum quam sodales sit amet. Ut ex magna, tempor nec ex sed, ornare ornare sem. Proin gravida turpis urna, vitae posuere purus consequat sit amet. Donec laoreet tempor massa. Praesent porta mauris vitae neque condimentum, non volutpat felis eleifend.
    </p>
    <p>
    Aliquam aliquam a est eget cursus. Ut eu tempus justo, rutrum dapibus ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ornare nisi sit amet arcu semper maximus. Praesent eu augue eget mi sodales sodales. Praesent sodales neque malesuada, euismod est in, lobortis turpis. Nam blandit facilisis mauris. Ut ac ex rhoncus, ornare velit ac, aliquam nibh. Quisque euismod mauris quis nisl consectetur vulputate. Pellentesque mattis, tellus ut dictum dictum, urna ligula sodales magna, euismod malesuada ipsum quam nec elit.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section class="step step3">
    <h1>3</h1>
    <p>
      Nulla rhoncus aliquam mauris, eu pretium dolor auctor in. Maecenas a sollicitudin dolor, eget commodo quam. Proin et dui sed ligula vulputate egestas. Quisque eget augue vitae purus placerat pharetra. Aliquam rhoncus convallis lorem, sed facilisis odio blandit scelerisque. Vivamus viverra urna ac nulla interdum, eget ullamcorper leo maximus. Mauris nec feugiat enim. Nam congue, dui sit amet vestibulum posuere, leo mauris fermentum lorem, eget bibendum velit nunc quis leo.
    </p>
    <p>
    Curabitur eget ullamcorper justo, sit amet dictum neque. Fusce vitae ligula et felis auctor vulputate vel suscipit nibh. Integer a felis varius purus vestibulum viverra. Morbi venenatis placerat augue sit amet commodo. Sed dapibus molestie eros, vitae ultrices nunc commodo aliquam. Vivamus tempus mollis massa vel egestas. Donec ut ante quis eros commodo volutpat. Proin sem nisi, viverra ac sem tristique, consectetur laoreet sapien. Vivamus suscipit orci vel euismod scelerisque. Nullam sed pulvinar tellus. Nullam pulvinar arcu eget nibh rutrum, eget faucibus ligula ullamcorper.
    </p>
  </section>
  
  <section class="step step4">
    <h1>4</h1>
    <p>
    Duis sit amet eros non est lacinia posuere et et ex. Proin in dui ornare ex eleifend pharetra. Etiam eros urna, euismod eget porttitor et, tempor quis turpis. Nullam sollicitudin suscipit lorem, maximus pellentesque turpis dictum sed. Integer fringilla gravida tellus sit amet facilisis. Pellentesque vel porta justo. Proin vehicula eget tortor ut condimentum. Phasellus interdum urna a condimentum dapibus. Sed commodo elit a metus vestibulum, ac vehicula mi tincidunt. Duis ante quam, posuere eget purus et, mollis congue tortor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc quis orci porttitor, dictum libero sit amet, feugiat ipsum.
    </p>
    <p>
    Nunc auctor lorem vitae neque sodales cursus. Sed scelerisque tempor tincidunt. Praesent eu pretium mi. Duis vitae venenatis nunc. Integer dolor sapien, vehicula ac dui id, fermentum malesuada justo. Donec ullamcorper enim sed nulla egestas condimentum. Etiam vitae dapibus sem, ut efficitur nulla. Donec laoreet, nunc quis aliquet blandit, erat nibh facilisis nibh, ut fermentum nisl dolor vel dui. Nunc pulvinar scelerisque urna, ut dictum purus placerat ac.
    </p>
    <p>
    Nam mattis ipsum at metus placerat maximus. Sed sed enim nunc. Aenean dapibus, lorem non congue volutpat, tortor orci egestas leo, eu efficitur erat orci sit amet libero. Praesent quis convallis metus. Cras eget ligula nec tortor mollis vestibulum et facilisis tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed malesuada, lectus vulputate tristique mattis, lacus nisl tempus sem, in aliquet dolor neque sed nisl. Nulla facilisi. Nulla a pharetra felis, eu aliquet urna. Phasellus mattis mauris eget mauris laoreet, et accumsan magna laoreet. Maecenas a condimentum diam. Integer et neque odio.
    </p>
  </section>
  
  <section class="step step5">
    <h1>5</h1>
    <p>
    Etiam feugiat tempus nibh, quis mattis enim porttitor eu. Praesent congue gravida nisi, sit amet convallis lectus sagittis et. Praesent rutrum ante nec lectus congue, congue pharetra sem efficitur. Vivamus eros mauris, pellentesque in aliquam at, vehicula consequat neque. Sed in pharetra lorem. Vivamus porttitor lectus risus. Vestibulum malesuada vestibulum ullamcorper. Nulla lacus purus, faucibus sit amet urna ac, placerat congue lectus. Ut iaculis risus eu pretium cursus. Quisque ac pharetra orci, ut convallis libero. Praesent auctor commodo quam sit amet aliquam. Integer tortor neque, cursus sit amet maximus sit amet, ultrices sed arcu. Nulla volutpat libero non ipsum auctor consectetur. Cras non malesuada felis, vel maximus ligula. Curabitur euismod porta semper. Ut posuere eget libero ac consequat.
    </p>
    <p>
    Mauris tristique, leo sit amet aliquam varius, urna elit scelerisque nisi, non iaculis lectus augue id sapien. Phasellus euismod tellus in sodales finibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean malesuada sapien quis eleifend volutpat. Cras quam arcu, iaculis vel ornare vulputate, feugiat quis enim. Nullam auctor, libero vestibulum imperdiet tincidunt, justo tellus varius justo, a finibus magna purus eu est. Nam interdum odio in ligula ultricies, quis pulvinar lectus pulvinar. Fusce quis sem tincidunt, mattis massa eu, bibendum enim. Vivamus arcu arcu, aliquam eget suscipit id, tempor sed nibh. Nullam mi mauris, facilisis vitae massa a, facilisis vulputate velit. Phasellus facilisis egestas erat id elementum.
    </p>
    <p>
    Proin non libero tortor. Nam scelerisque vel odio interdum pretium. Sed non metus magna. Praesent ullamcorper venenatis risus, quis semper purus. Donec vitae lectus id magna dignissim laoreet at ac urna. Aenean sapien dolor, egestas vitae nisl quis, ornare ullamcorper nibh. Nulla facilisi. Fusce maximus dapibus scelerisque. Donec sagittis leo mi, eget aliquet odio sodales rhoncus.
    </p>
  </section>

</div>

<button>scroll-snap-stop: always</button>



My experience testing this with Safari on Mac is that although always does indeed make the stopping more consistent, it is still possible to scroll through snap points if you drag your fingers across the trackpad rather than doing a quick flick or swipe. Quick flicks work consistently, but by dragging it is possible to scroll through snap points without stopping.
